# Cloudfront s3 bucket settings

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to set up cloudfront to serve my S3 images.  I have one origin working to serve my javascript, css and fonts (coming from heroku).

I created a new origin for my images:

```
Origin Domain Name: MYBUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com
```

This was auto-populated by cloudfront.  I left origin path blank.  Restrict Bucket Access is set to 'No'

**The URL from s3 works fine:**
http://MYBUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/people/pics/000/000/674/medium/open-uri20150807-28718-re2542?1439005733

**Replacing the URL with cloudfront does not:**
http://CLOUDFRONTURL.cloudfront.net/people/pics/000/000/674/medium/open-uri20150807-28718-re2542?1439005733

I invalidated the cache but no luck.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't mention setting [path patterns](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern).  With multiple origins, you have to specify path patterns so Cloudfront knows which origin to check, for each object.

Comment: Thank you so much, It's working!  You should submit this as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

As  Michael commented:

If you have multiple origins, you have to log in to cloudfront, click 'Behaviors' and create a behavior with a new 'path pattern'.

In my case `assets` has my Heroku deploy as the origin.  Images for my models come from the `s3` bucket.

```
Precedence   |   Path Pattern    |   Origin
   0         | assets/bootstrap  |  my-heroku-assets
   1         |      people/*     |  my-aws-bucket
```